# Why is jquery beforeunload showing a message even when returning null in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

This code will cause Internet Explorer to show the 'Are you sure you want to leave?' message every time, even when dirtyMessage is null. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
  var dirty = didUserUpdateSomething();  

  if (dirty) {
    return "You will lose your changes.";
  }
  return null;
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently returning null is the problem. Works in all other browsers except good old IE. The solution is not to return anything (undefined):

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
  var dirty = didUserUpdateSomething();  

  if (dirty) {
    return "You will lose your changes.";
  }
  // notice that in case of no dirty message we do not return anything. 
  // having 'return null;' will make IE show a popup with 'null'.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `beforeunload` in IE is a bit quirky;  Returning ANYTHING in your event handler (even null) will cause it to pop up a box asking the user if the user is quite sure they want to leave the page.

You can try this as a possible workaround:

```
var beforeUnloadFired = false;
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function (event) {
    if (!beforeUnloadFired) {
        beforeUnloadFired = true;
        event.returnValue = "You have attempted to leave this page.  Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?";
    }
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        ResetUnloadFired();
    }, 10);
});

function ResetUnloadFired() {
    beforeUnloadFired = false;
}
```

Couple of references:  [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/beforeunload?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Mozilla_event_reference%2Fbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/beforeunload?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Mozilla_event_reference/beforeunload)

and

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536907(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

NOTE: see the "Remarks" for pertinent information within that second reference.

Comment: Feel free to refactor for your `didUserUpdateSomething();` function